# How to use map service legend on ArcGIS Online?

Tags: legend, arcgis-online

How can I use the legend of a mapservice as part of a AGOL generated webmap?

This is **[the map I have created](http://dpwh.maps.arcgis.com/apps/OnePane/basicviewer/index.html?appid=9fe61206457b4294b47dc0ddc3c7a0cd)** which does not have a legend

And this is the map service in use
[code]https://203.177.0.139/ArcGIS/rest/services/Leng/2013_Road_Data_elf/MapServer/[/code]

Pretty sure it has a legend because this has the correct content
[code]https://203.177.0.139/ArcGIS/rest/services/Leng/2013_Road_Data_elf/MapServer/legend[/code]

---

Could this still be a certificate issue? Our certificate is not signed or anything. So we are placing the map service address as an exception to an internet browser for it to allow access to "unsigned" content. By doing this we are able to use the AGOL webmaps with mapservice from an unsigned source.

What doesnt seem to make sense is why, after doing the exception list, would AGOL allow features to be drawn but not the legends (or the info configured for the pop-up dialog, as we also recently found out). What specific about these that makes them excluded?

Comment: You could scrape the drawingInfo for each layer:

https://203.177.0.139/ArcGIS/rest/services/Leng/2013_Road_Data_elf/MapServer/0?f=json&pretty=true

Comment: The drawinInfo referes to the symbology, right? Isn't it needed as data for the legend?

Answer (score 3):

You could try using a legend/TOC widget such as [**this one**](https://wheaton.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9b6280a6bfb0430f8d1ebc969276b109#).

It scrapes the layer definitions for you and builds a TOC, including layer visibility control (optional?).

[image]

Comment: I have before, but not when combined with AGOL. I'll try that one, thanks.

Comment: Having learned more about AGOL since this was posted, I think the preferred approach would be to create a web map that uses your map service(s) as a layer, which should allow you to use the AGOL legend tools. Haven't tried it myself yet though.